# How to have a list from inheritance classes?

Tags: java, list, object, methods, extension-methods

I have 3 classes and one when I store my lists.

```
  public class Extension<T> implements Serializable
```

And 3 like this:

```
    public abstract class Person extends Exstension implements Serializable {
        // etc.
    }

    public abstract class Man extends Person {
List<Man>...
        // etc.
    }

    public abstract class Woman extends Person {
List<Woman>...
        // etc.
    }
```

In Main class I have:

```
Man man1 = new Man(....);
Woman woman1 = new Woman(....);

ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Storage"));
Extension.save(oos);
oos.close();

try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Storage"))) {
    Extension.load(ois);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Brak ekstensji!");
}
```

And when I want to read every man and woman in Like this:

```
System.out.println(Person.getExtension(Person.class));
```

And its give me : null.
What should I add to my code?
Thanks!

Comment: `public abstract class Man` but then `Man man1 = new Man(....)`.  How does this code even compile?  Where is the `List<>`?  Why use generics when no generic type is specified?

Comment: You did not include `Ekstensja`, your exception handling is a problem (don't 'print and continue' - no matter how often that anti-pattern shows up in examples), and you aren't using generics here (`extends Extension` is a problem; it needs to be `extends Extension<Something>`). The design in general seems problematic. I'm not sure anybody can help you out without considerably more source code and information. Why did you design it this way, what are you trying to do, etcetera.

Comment: I have list of Man and Woman in this classes but i write only List. yes now its correct code. What is wrong?